# How to calculate the quantum yield of a photochemical process?

Tags: kinetics, photochemistry

> I have that $\pu{100 ml}$ of an aqueous solution containing $\pu{1.0 mM}$  $\ce{H2O2}$, $\pu{100 mM}$ $\ce{CH3OH}$ and $\pu{200 mM}$ DMSO are exposed to monochromatic light with a wavelength of $300$ nm. The incident light intensity is $\pu{2mW/cm2}$ and the exposed area is $\pu{4cm2}$. The absorbance of the solution at $300$ nm (which depends only on  $\ce{H2O2}$) was measured to be $0.25$. Only the homolysis of $\ce{H2O2}$ to two hydroxyl radicals needs to be taken into consideration. The hydroxyl radicals formed react with  $\ce{CH3OH}$ at a rate constant of $\pu{1.0E8M^{-1}s^{-1}}$ and with DMSO at a rate constant of $\pu{2.0E9M^{-1}s^{-1}}$. The product of the reaction with $\ce{CH3OH}$ is formaldehyde ($\ce{CH2O}$). The concentration of formaldehyde as a function of reaction time was measured and is given below. Based on the data below, determine the quantum yield for photoinduced homolysis of $\ce{H2O2}$.
> $$
> \begin{array}{rl}
> \hline 
> \textrm{time}/\pu{h} & [\ce{CH2O}]/\pu{M} \\
> \hline
> 0 & 0 \\
> 1 & \pu{7.7E-7} \\ 
> 2 & \pu{1.5E-6} \\ 
> 3 & \pu{2.3E-6} \\ 
> 4 & \pu{3.1E-6} \\ 
> 5 & \pu{3.8E-6} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

I hope this isn't closed off as "off-topic" since it is quite a long question but I genuinely don't know where to start on this. I feel that there is so much information and I can't quite determine what is useful and what has just been added to confuse us.

I wanted to start by writing all the reactions and then use the steady-state assumption to determine the rate equation for $\ce{CH2O}$ but even there I got stuck. From what I have understood two of the reactions are:

$$\ce{H2O2 -> 2OH-}$$

$$\ce{2OH- + CH3OH -> CH2O + 2 H2O}$$

**But** I don't know how the third reaction with DMSO will look like and can't seem to find anything online. I don't know if the way I am trying to solve this problem is the correct way since I don't really know if I am supposed to solve for  $\ce{CH2O}$ and then plot it to get something from the plot so I would truly appreciate if someone could push me in the right direction or link helpful examples or other useful information that might help me solve this. Thank you!

**EDIT**

With your help I have tried to being answering the problem but I come across some things that I don't know how to tackle. I began with calculating that the incident light intensity should be $2$ mW/cm$^2$ * $4$cm$^2$ = $8$ mW. By using Lambert-Beers law I calculated the intensity of the outgoing light as:

$$log\frac{I_0}{I} = A$$

$$I = \frac{I_0}{10^A} = \frac{8mW}{10^{0.25}} = 4.49 = 4.5 mW$$

Then the amount of absorbed light is: ΔI = I$_0$ - I = $8 - 4.5 = 3.5 mW$

So from this I can now calculate the denominator of the quantum yield fraction (I call it b for amount of absorbed photons) from the equation:

$$b = \frac{absorbed light}{energy per mol photons} = \frac{ΔIλ}{hcN_A} = \frac{3.5*10^{-3}Js^{-1}* 300 * 10^{-9}m}{6.625*10^{-34}Js^{-1}*3*10^8ms^{-1}*6.02*10^{23}mol}$$
$$= 8.78*10^{-9} smol^{-1}$$

I don't think this is the correct answer since the units don't add up. Should I maybe take the intensity times the number of hours ($5$h) to get the intensity only in Joules?

Then if I write out the rate equations:

$$\frac{d[CH_2O]}{dt}=k_2[OH^*]^2[CH_3OH]$$

$$\frac{d[OH^*]}{dt}=k_1[H_2O_2]-k_2[OH^*]^2[CH_3OH] → [OH^*]^2 = \frac{k_1[H_2O_2]}{k_2[CH_3OH]}$$

which then gives:

$$\frac{d[CH_2O]}{dt}=k_1[H_2O_2]$$

I don't really understand what use I have of this in order to calculate the number of molecules of the reactant which is used..

Comment: Well, not writing anion instead of radical would be a start... BTW why do you know how to make a table and not about mhchem or mathrm?

Comment: This is a messy problem. As to DMSO as long as it does not produce formaldehyde it reduces this yield by a lot $10^8/(10^8+20\cdot10^8)$. Next the product yield is tiny anyway so $[H_2O_2],[CH_3OH],[DMSO]$ are effectively constant. You know from absorbance and Beers law  what fraction of energy is absorbed, you should assume each photon breaks a bond. Write down the rate equations. Ignore product from DMSO. You will need to integrate to get total yield as I assume illumination is continuous.

Comment: If DMSO interfere I think it should also be counted. The quantum yield would be the practical one on the products of interest. How many of the product formaldehyde / how many photons.

Comment: @porphyrin Thank you for your help! I have added some of my new calculations and questions to my original question under edit. I would truly appreciate it if You could take a look.

Comment: You are at steady state so $d[OH]/dt =2 k_{abs}[H2O2] - k_2[OH][MeOH]=0$. You get $k_{abs}$ from the number of photons/sec converted into 'moles of photons'/sec (Einsteins?) and you can then use data in table. You can assume pseudo first order as the amount of OH produced is tiny compared to other species.